# Unityちゃんのインポート

Tags: unity3d

3Dゲームの玉転がしチュートリアルを作成したのでキャラクターの移動に挑戦したくなりました
そこで公式からUnityちゃんをダウンロードしてインポートしたのですが再生マークを押すとコンパイルエラーが出てしまい動きません
インポートしたままスクリプトなどはいじっていないのでインポート方法がおかしいのでしょうか？
どなたか教えていただければ幸いです
Unityのバージョンは2018.3.6f1
Unityちゃんは1.2.1です

追記
インポートの方法ですが公式サイトから利用規約に同意して「ユニティちゃん 3Dモデルデータ」をダウンロード「UnityChan_1_2_1.unitypackage」を入手
上記の通りプロジェクトを作成し、床を追加した段階で先ほどの「UnityChan_1_2_1.unitypackage」をダブルクリックで実行
表示されたimportをクリックしてインポート
この時点で実行ボタンを押すと「All compiler errors have to be fixed before you can enter playmode!」と表示されてしまいます

http://unity-chan.com

さらに追記
コンソールに

```
Assets/UnityChan/Scripts/AutoBlink.cs(8,23): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Policy' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Security' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

と表示されていました
サイトで利用規約に同意したものとは別に何かの同意が必要なのでしょうか

Answer (score 0, accepted):

試していないですが、using System.Security.Policy を変更するとエラーは解消されるようです。

https://www.ipentec.com/document/unity-error-cs0234-the-type-or-namespace-name-policy-does-not-exist-in-namespace-system-security

Comment: ありがとうございます！１行コメントアウトしたらどうさしました！